# fading out php echo messages

Tags: php, jquery

I want to fade out php echo message. Here is my php code:

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $to = 'ajay.k@enexl.com';
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
        $mailSubject = "Contact request from " .$name;
        $txt = "name : ".$name.".\n\nSubject : ".$subject.".\n\nMail id : ".$email."\n\nMessage : ".$message;
        $headers = "From: ".$email ;
        mail($to,$mailSubject,$txt,$headers);
        $data = array();
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        //echo json_encode($data);  
        echo "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>";
        echo "<p id='#text'>Your email was sent! One of our team members would contact you shortly!</p>"; // success message
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "$(function(){";
        echo "$('#text').fadeOut(5000);";  
        echo "});";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Mail was not sent, make sure that all fields are filled in";
    }

?>
```

When the form data gets submitted, successfully, I get the response as `Your email was sent! One of our team members would contact you shortly!`. However it doesn't fade out as expected. How can I make it fade out?

Answer (score 3):

Dont use `#` in you id qualifier. `#text` says to find an element with id `text` not `#text`

```
echo "<p id='#text'>Your email was sent! One of our team members would contact you shortly!</p>"; // success message
```

should be

```
echo "<p id='text'>Your email was sent! One of our team members would contact you shortly!</p>"; // success message
```

Comment: Oh, crap... didn't see that :D anyway, thanks a ton :)